# Fetch a different Firestore collection in each instance of forEach?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a forEach that runs for each `item` document in my `items` Firestore collection. Each `item` document also has it's own subcollection of `parts`. I want to spit out the list of `parts` under each `item` so we can see all the parts that we have entered in stock under each section.

**What I tried**

I tried creating an array for the inner loop. Each instance of the forEach would fill the array with it's data, but the following loop would overwrite that array data with it's own data. In the end, all items would show the same collection of parts.

**Firestore**
[image: Firestore]

**Output**
[image: Output]

**HTML Code**

```
  <div class="ui card" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <h4 class="header">{{item.name}}</h4>
    <table class="ui table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**TypeScript Code (so far)**

```
itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Items>;
items: Observable<Items[]>;

ngOnInit(){
    let path = 'Items';

    this.itemsCollection= this.afs.collection(path);
    this.items= this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: So you basically wnat to query the database to get all the parts from within all your items (documents)?

Comment: Yes sir, I sure do.

Comment: And you want to achieve this in a single query?

Comment: There's no reason it needs to be done in a single query.

Comment: Then why not to do multiple queries?

Comment: Because I don't know how to make the other query.